# Is it possible to connect to an embedded DB with Raven Management Studio

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm playing with Raven DB and am wondering if it's possible to connect to an embedded DB with Raven Management Studio. Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understood you correct and you mean the Web UI, you simply have to enable the embedded web server.

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
  DataDirectory = "Data",
  UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};
```

See http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded

Also make sure to include Raven.Studio.xap in the root of your web application

Comment: This kind of works, but now I get this error message: Missing file

Could not find file Raven.Server.xap, which contains the RavenDB Studio functionality. Please copy the Raven.Server.xap file to the base directory of RavenDB and try again.

Comment: And once you have included the Raven.Studio.xap file, it should just work.

Comment: If you have RunInMemory=true and you're in a web application, copy the Raven.Studio.xap into the root of your *web application*! I missed this for a while!

Comment: What about if you're trying to debug unit tests? Ideally I'd like to break anywhere and view the DB in its current state in Studio.

Comment: @subkamran have you found an answer to your question?