# Running RavenDB as an EmbeddableDocumentStore and accessing RavenDB Management Studio

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm playing with an embedded RavenDB => `RavenDB-Embedded.1.0.499` package installed via NuGet in Visual Studio 2010. It's being used in a current project that I started after reading this excellent MSDN article:

[Embedding RavenDB into an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/hh547101%28en-us%29.aspx)

Now I'd like to access the [RavenDB Management Studio](http://ayende.com/blog/125953/peeking-behind-the-curtains-the-new-ravendb-management-studio) (Web UI).

I followed the steps described here: [Is it possible to connect to an embedded DB with Raven Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947092/114029) and here [Running RavenDB in embedded mode with HTTP enabled](http://ravendb.net/faq/embedded-with-http) but I didn't get the point.

This is the code I'm using to initialize the `DocumentStore`:

```
_documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            };
```

and this is the `ConnectionString` present in `Web.config`:

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="DataDir = ~\App_Data\Database" />
```

I also read the steps described in [RavenDB: Embedded Mode](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2011/08/ravendb-embedded-mode/). I tried to start the server manually:

```
// Start the HTTP server manually
var server = new RavenDbHttpServer(documentStore.Configuration,
documentStore.DocumentDatabase);

server.Start();
```

but the above code seems outdated since I have no `RavenDbHttpServer`, `documentStore.Configuration` and `documentStore.DocumentDatabase`. I managed to find `Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer` but the other objects are missing in the `_documentStore`.

So, the question is:

How can I hit the Web UI to visualize my embedded database docs? What's the URL I should put in my browser address bar?

Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've found a way of getting it to work. As I described in my blog post it may not be the best approach but it does work:

[RavenDB Embedded with Management Studio UI](http://www.leniel.net/2011/11/ravendb-embedded-management-studio-ui.html)

Note: one downside of the above approach is that I'm not able to access the database in my app because once it has been opened by the server it gets locked. This way I have to stop the server and then reload my app in the browser.

I hope RavenDB's gurus out there have a better/correct approach... just let us know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never had to run the server manually in order to access the management studio.  The only few steps that haven't been mentioned in your question that I usually do:

```
// Add the following line prior to calling documentStore.Initialize()
Raven.Database.Server.NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
```

Copy `Raven.Studio.xap` into the root folder of my web project.

When my web application is running, the RavenDB Management Studio is then accessible at http://localhost:8080.

Comment: OMG: this is weird... I had tried http://localhost:8080 but it did not work at first. Now I got it working without even adding `EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext`. Go figure. I think I had another service running on port 8080 on that first try... Thanks John!

Comment: This works but if I debug a unit test, it stops execution of the HTTP server so I can't use it unless I don't debug which means I can't debug my tests and view the studio which means this is useless. Is there a way to avoid this?