# Browse Embedded in Windows Form RavenDb database

Tags: ravendb

I have an embedded database in windows forms app. Is it possible to browse it using ravendb management studio? All examples that I found concerned used web app approach.

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947092/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-an-embedded-db-with-raven-management-studio

Comment: I saw that example, but it is about web application. How to apply it to Windows Forms ?

Comment: I tried to add UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true setting, but initialization returns HttpListenerException: "Access is denied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by Fitzchak Yitzchaki was almost 100% correct(there wasn't any mention about Windows Forms). Lots of credits go also to desigenr of this database who helped me with some problems.

So to summarize what needs to be done to acces RavenDb Management Studio:

1. Set `UseEmbeddedHttpServer` as in answer provided by Fitzchak
   Yitzchaki.
2. Raven.Studio.xap must be in same directory as application main
   executable file.
3. Application has to be run with admin privileges("Run as admin").

I hope this post will help someone.